# Flutter. Container border gradient. White to transparent

Tags: dart, flutter

Do You know any way how to make a container border with gradient? I want to make it to fade from one color to the same with 0 opacity.

Also i was thinking about to use a blend mode, i dont think its a good idea

at this moment i see only one way. To make it with flare:
https://www.2dimensions.com/a/stellarcreed/files/flare/border-gradient/preview

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Center(
  child: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.purple,
      gradient: new LinearGradient(
        colors: [Colors.red, Colors.cyan],
      ),
    ),
    child: new FlutterLogo(
      size: 200.0,
    )
  ),
);
```

Here is more information [regarding this question](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20).

Comment: No, this gradient is for a container, not for a border

Comment: i was thinking to do something similar: https://www.2dimensions.com/a/stellarcreed/files/flare/border-gradient/preview

Comment: I see, what about using one container with the grading and another one on top of it, a smaller one, with a solid color. If you wish to use a transparent box with gradient borders, then you should look into doing the same thing but with clipping.(I'm fairly new to flutter, so this part is speculation)

Comment: i was thinking about two containers too, but the thing is that i have a background and i need to see throw the smaller circle somehow. Will try to do clipping and if there is no result going back to flare

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should work, use [LinerGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html), you can adjust the `Alignment` for different directions. But this is for the container, not the border. You can stack other components on top of it.

```
Container(
    height: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Styles.colorWhite,
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
            begin:  Alignment(0.0, -1.0),
            end: Alignment(0.0, 0.2),
            colors: [Color(0x1AFFFFFF),Color(0x4DFFFFFF), Colors.white])
        ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, bottom: 20, left: 15, right: 15),
),
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf2Q1.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think currently the only way to do this is to stack container with gradient colors below your container.
And keep the size of the gradient color container a little bigger than your upper container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_borders

```
Eg.:
     Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: const GradientBoxBorder(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red]),
          width: 4,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
      ),
    ),
```